# Restoring from a snapshot

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, restore, snapshot, azure-cli

I have created a snapshot of my VM in Azure a few weeks ago using the script below.

```
$mydiskId = $(az vm show  --resource-group "myResourceGroup" --name "myVM" --query "storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.id")
az snapshot create --name "myTestSnapShot" --resource-group --resource-group "MW-ENGINEERING-USEAST" --source $mydiskId
```

Now I am looking to restore that snapshot. Googling provides many links such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-restore-disk). However, these talk about creating a recovery point/storage account as well. This left me confused as to when creating the snapshot, did I miss any of those steps. None of the steps described in the document for restoring the snapshot uses any id of the snapshot I created through the commands above. Can someone please help me understand what did I miss? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [linked document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/tutorial-restore-disk) is to **restore the whole VM** or individual files. Before this, you need to enable **Azure Backup** to create recovery points that are stored in geo-redundant recovery vaults.

If you don't enable Azure Backup, consider there is a scenario where you want to get certain data from the snapshot without restoring the complete VM. In that case, one of the excellent ways is to create a VM from the snapshot and get the specific data that you need. In this way, you can create a different VM name and get the original data from the source VM. You can read [this blog](https://azurelessons.com/create-azure-virtual-machine-from-a-snapshot/) for more details.

To use Azure CLI to create an Azure VM from snapshots, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-manage-disks#take-a-disk-snapshot) for more details.

```
#Create snapshot
osdiskid=$(az vm show \
   -g myResourceGroupDisk \
   -n myVM \
   --query "storageProfile.osDisk.managedDisk.id" \
   -o tsv)

az snapshot create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroupDisk \
    --source "$osdiskid" \
    --name osDisk-backup

#Create disk from snapshot
az disk create \
   --resource-group myResourceGroupDisk \
   --name mySnapshotDisk \
   --source osDisk-backup

#Create a new virtual machine from the snapshot disk.
az vm create \
    --resource-group myResourceGroupDisk \
    --name myVM \
    --attach-os-disk mySnapshotDisk \
    --os-type linux
```

Comment: thanks for the info. The blog you referred to is using via power-shell. Is there any way to do it all through azure cli?

Comment: Any more questions? Does the reply solve your issue?

Comment: Looks helpful. I am going to give it a try some point today. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It worked on my side, if it also works for you please accept this answer.

Comment: I absolutely will. Have to deal with some distractions but will do once  I get a chance.